# System design using oops

Tags: java, oop

I have a class for Machine.

```
public class Machine {
    private InternalCombustionEngine engine = new InternalCombustionEngine(FuelType.PETROL);

    public int produceWidgets(int quantity) {
        engine.start();
        int cost = 0;

        if (engine.isRunning()) {
            cost = produce(quantity);
        }

        engine.stop();

        return cost;
    }

    private int produce(int quantity) {
        int batch = 0;
        int batchCount = 0;
        int costPerBatch = 0;

        if (engine.getFuelType() == FuelType.PETROL) {
            costPerBatch = 9;
        } else if (engine.getFuelType() == FuelType.DIESEL) {
            costPerBatch = 12;
        }

        while (batch < quantity) {
            batch = batch + 8;
            batchCount++;
        }

        return batchCount * costPerBatch;
    }


}
```

And InternalCombustion Engine class as follows:

```
public class InternalCombustionEngine {

    private boolean running;
    private int fuelLevel;
    private FuelType requiredFuelType;
    private FuelType fuelType;

    public InternalCombustionEngine(FuelType requiredFuelType) {
        this.requiredFuelType = requiredFuelType;
        running = false;
        fuelLevel = 0;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (fuelLevel > 0 && requiredFuelType.equals(fuelType)) {
            running = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not able to start engine.");
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    public void fill(FuelType fuelType, int fuelLevel) {
        if (fuelLevel >= 0 && fuelLevel <= 100) {
            this.fuelLevel = fuelLevel;
        }
        else if (fuelLevel > 100) {
            this.fuelLevel = 100;
        }
        else {
            this.fuelLevel = 0;
        }

        this.fuelType = fuelType;
    }

    public FuelType getFuelType() {
        return  requiredFuelType;
    }
}
```

I want to add another engine say steam engine class performing almost similar operations as InternalCombustion Engine class and my Machine class should support both these. And also if anyone wants to add another engine in future he/she can add it. How can I do that using oops design principles and test driven development.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an interface called something like 'Engine' with methods start(), stop(), isRunning(), fill(...), and getFuelType(), and then having both SteamEngine and InternalCombustionEngine implement that interface is likely the best approach.

Comment: how machine class will support both?

Comment: and also can't we go for abstract class in place of interface?

Comment: When defining the variable 'engine', you would do: private Engine engine = new InternalCombustionEngine(FeulType.PETROL); This lets you just have to change InternalCombustionEngine to SteamEngine if you want to change the type.

Comment: Yes you can use an abstract class as well, but using interfaces provides a much more flexible architecture in case more changes occur in the future, since you can implement multiple interfaces, but only extend one class in Java.

Comment: How to do it with test driven  development. sorry I am new to this, so don't have much idea

Comment: For how to do that, I recommend reading up on what test-driven development is, since explaining how to do that here would exceed the scope of stackoverflow's purpose. Finding a tutorial or reading on Wikipedia about TDD should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

The basic idea: you have to provide a contract between your Machine and an engine it can use. Whatever engine you connect to your Machine, it must provide known methods, so the Machine can control it.

An example of an interface you can use:

```
public interface Engine {

    public void start();

    public void stop();

    public void fill(FuelType fuelType, int fuelLevel);

    public FuelType getFuelType();

}
```

Now, each engine must implement this interface:

```
public class InternalCombustionEngine implements Engine {
        public void start() {
             //implementation
        }

        public void stop() {
            //implementation
        }

        public void fill(FuelType fuelType, int fuelLevel) {
            //implementation
        }

        public FuelType getFuelType() {
            //implementation
        }
}
```

And finally, in order to be able to use an Engine, you'd better provide a constructor for you `Machine` class accepting **any** object that implements `Engine` interface:

```
public class Machine {

     public Machine(Engine engine) {    
         this.engine = engine;
     }

     //.......

}
```

This approach gives you a flexible and scalable way of replacing either engine or machine independently to each other. And provide a good possibility of developing each component separately.

Comment: thanks buddy. How to do it with test driven development. sorry I am new to this, so don't have much idea

Comment: @zaib11, Test Driven Development is a methodology. You should not confuse it with an application design. If you want to follow it, you'd better look at [Test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). The basic idea: you create a group of tests first that satisfy buisness requirements. And then you write code to pass these tests and thus, develop your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

Implementing an `interface` which is basically a class that contains only abstract methods and static or final variables. You can implement it in you classes with the keyword `implements`.

Another way is to use an abstract class. It can contain abstract and non-abstract methods, final, non-final, static and non-static variables. You can implement it with the keyword `extends`.